# Create git repository using tortisegit

Tags: git, svn, github, git-svn, tortoisegit

I am facing the issue to create the git repository using tortisegit and git gui tool. Can any one help me to provide the steps to create the git repository using GUI tools.

I have checked in stackoverflow for same and found enough.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Git GUI for windows and use it easily. I created the repository in the GitHub and then use windows UI to clone and work on it.
You can download git UI from below location.However as I have read UI is not supporting all kind of master level git functionality which you can use from git bash/command line.

Git for windows
http://git-scm.com/downloads

Git UI for windows
http://git-scm.com/downloads/guis

Also you can try below link  on using tortisegit

http://dbanck.de/2009/10/08/github-windows-and-tortoisegit-part-1-installing-pulling/

Comment: thanks, But I have not get the appropriate answer. I have create repository using tortisegit. Also, I have done all the things as you suggested. thanks

Comment: @Amit, from that last link have you also tried "Now your [sic] ready to create a local repository. Create an empty folder and right-click into it. Choose 'Git Create repository here'."? http://dbanck.de/static/images/091008_7_full.png

Comment: The OP is correct that this answer doesn't really answer his question. Perhaps you could remove the non-Tortoise part of the answer and add more details about Tortoise from your last link? We prefer answers that contain the important bits directly in case the link goes dead.

Comment: @Chris, I have already mentioned that I tried the the link as per suggested and that not works properly.

Comment: @Amit, saying that it doesn't work properly isn't very helpful. *How* does it not work properly? Do you see the Tortoise menu options? Can you select "Git Create repository here", but it fails somehow? Do you get any error messages?

Comment: @Chris, I have got the solution. As per my exploration we can create the repository using the tortisegit. But this repository only work as local and work all the local system operation and we could't sync the local repository to cloud.